# importing java subpackages on eclipse

Tags: java, import, thrift

Hi is it possible to import packages in java in similar way to relative paths?

For instance I have created my project in the package: com.test.calculator

Then I copied and pasted a folder in the com.test.calculator package, so the packages pasted look like this: com.test.calculator.org.apache.thrift.async and similar things. But now inside the java files in the folders, when they try to import org.apache.thrift.async for instance, it say that it cannot be resolved. Is there a way to make it notice that it is all under com.test.caclulator and consider the package path as a relative route?

Thanks

Comment: Haven't tried anything like that before. But what's the big deal of grabbing the jar file or using something like Maven to install the dependancy?

Comment: there is no jar file, I've never used maven

Comment: I am talking about when you are trying to import `org.apache.thrift.async`. If you used Thrift on your project `com.test.calculator`, then you had to of grabbed it's .jar file somehow

Comment: yeah, everything is provided inside the org folder but there is no jar file

Comment: Even in this case I think you should give full path of package. Like com.test.calculator.org.apache.thrift.async

Comment: The answer is no. But this: "For instance I have created my project in the package: com.test.calculator " is also not true. You just created that package as part of creating your project; you are free to add many more, including your org.apache.thrift one. Just copy the directories to where the "com" directory is of your existing project package.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, just adding the .org,blah.blah packages next to com.blah i was able to reference them without problem =)

Comment: In Eclipse You can add next folders of type "source" (tab from Build Path)